# Which child class extended the parent class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, parent-child, es6-class

Assume I have the following JavaScript code

```
class Parent {
  constructor () {
    console.log("parent");
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("child 1");
    super();
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("child 2");
    super();
  }
}

const c1 = new Child1; // Output: 'child 1' then 'parent'
const c2 = new Child2; // Output: 'child 2' then 'parent'
```

Now, is it possible to know, from within the class `Parent` which child class called it? Something like this:

```
class Parent {
  constructor () {
    console.log("parent");
    
    // If this class has a child, what's the child?
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Parent classes should not have code that applies only to specific child classes.  If you have a need for that, then you need a different way to code it, possibly by using the equivalent of virtual methods, methods which are defined in the parent, but whose implementation can be overriden by a child class.  This way, the child's implementation is all in the child and the parent does not ever need to know which child is running an instance.

Comment: For example, you could define a method call `getClassName()` and implement that in each child.  Then, anyone could call that to get the class name of the current instance.  But, it would be considered an anti-pattern to put code in the parent that branches based on what child instance it is.

Comment: You can also examine `this.constructor` and `this.constructor[Symbol.species]` on any properly constructed object.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Thank you

Comment: A much easier / more direct way of retrieving/accessing this information was to make use of [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) ... `class Parent { constructor () { console.log(new.target); console.log("parent"); } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the way to get the correct behaviour for your sub-class is to have a method that every sub-class overrides. Each sub-class has its correct implementation.

Alternatively, you could check the type of `this` against the various expected sub-class types. Rather than comparing class-types, it's still preferable to have a method and to override it.

You could also pass a sub-class name or an enumerator as a parameter to the super-class' constructor. Again, it's preferable to have a method and to override it.

Answer (score 1):

From my above comment ...

> *"A much easier / more direct way of retrieving/accessing this information was to make use of [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) ... `class Parent { constructor () { console.log(new.target); console.log("parent"); } }`"*

The OP's example code then changes to ...

```js
class Parent {
  constructor () {
    console.log(`${ new.target.name } ... ${ new.target }`);
    console.log("parent");
    console.log("\n");
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("child 1 ...");
    super();
  }
}
class Child2 extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("child 2");
    super();
  }
}
const c1 = new Child1;
const c2 = new Child2;
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Note**

While the above code answers the OP's question, it might not be the best solution for the OP's class design / type system. The real question is ...

***What does the OP need the very information for?***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. However I already resorted to the advice of the accepted answer and did a bunch of overrides.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));` ?

```
class Parent {
  constructor () {
    console.log("parent");
    
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)); // Should log Child2: {} or Child 1: {}
  }
}
```